# How to handle different JAVA version in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I was testing Android Studio 3.0 preview with some native java 8 features(such as lambda)

I got two modules (app, mylibrary)

In my app `build.gradle` file, I includes the library module.

```
implementation project(':mylibrary')
```

In the mylibrary `build.gradle` file, I specify the java version in order to test lambda expression.

```
compileOptions {
    android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
    android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8
}
```

It was working fine to me until I upgrade the android studio from canary 3 to canary 5, my approach is broken.

I got the following error message for dynamic

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
/Users/chchi/Documents/PayPal/Android/AS3.0Preview/app/src/main/java/com/example/chchi/myapplication/MainActivity.kt
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
...
...
Error:  ... 5 more
Error:...at bytecode offset 00000016
Error:locals[0000]: Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/IncrementalChange;
Error:locals[0001]: <invalid>
Error:...while working on block 0016
Error:...while working on method testJava8feature:()V
Error:...while processing testJava8feature ()V
Error:...while processing com/example/mylibrary/LamdaTest.class
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Unable to convert input to dex archive.
Information:BUILD FAILED in 8s
Information:40 errors
Information:1 warning
Information:See complete output in console
```

After I follow the instruction to bump the `minSdkVersion` to `26`. I am getting following error about converting to dex file.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Shouldn't happen
Error:com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext: Shouldn't happen
Error:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Error:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
Error:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
Error:  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
...
Error:Caused by: com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext: Shouldn't happen
Error:  at com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(ExceptionWithContext.java:45)
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.file.MixedItemSection.placeItems(MixedItemSection.java:320)
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.toDex0(DexFile.java:611)
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.toDex(DexFile.java:242)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.lambda$processJobChunk$0(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:118)
Error:  ... 5 more
Error:Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Shouldn't happen
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ValueEncoder.constantToValueType(ValueEncoder.java:276)
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ValueEncoder.writeConstant(ValueEncoder.java:137)
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ValueEncoder.writeArray(ValueEncoder.java:310)
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.file.CallSiteItem.place0(CallSiteItem.java:63)
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.file.OffsettedItem.place(OffsettedItem.java:242)
Error:  at com.android.dx.dex.file.MixedItemSection.placeItems(MixedItemSection.java:311)
Error:  ... 8 more
Error:...while placing call site{method-handle{invoke-static,method{java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;}}, string{"adder"}, proto{()Lcom/example/mylibrary/PayPalInterface;}, (II)V, method-handle{invoke-static,method{com.example.mylibrary.LamdaTest.lambda$testJava8feature$0:(II)V}}, (II)V}
Error:...while writing section 12
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Unable to convert input to dex archive.
Information:BUILD FAILED in 1s
Information:38 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Eventually, I had to bump and target all my module to `1.8` (no need to set `minSdkVersion` to `26`) in order to let compiler pass. Is there a way to make my library module use `1.8` only and whoever use my library can still stay at where they are now (`1.7`)?

If I am only use a certain features that have [high backward compatibility](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html), then why should I worry about if whoever uses my library target to `1.8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bug of the new Android Gradle Plugins - I'm facing same issue with my library project. Seems that `desugar` - that converts Java 8 bytecode to legacy bytecode -  is not working on library project.

I've reported issue to the google. Hope that it fixes.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63513242

Comment: I now just updated to canary 6 and it seems got fixed in this release. https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html (7/10/17)